# Small low frequency magnetic field measurement: soft iron or ferrite coil core?

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, electromagnetic

Disclaimer: I'm just computer scientist.

I'm planning a simple experiment that uses a coil to measure a small varying magnetic field. How small ? I don't know yet. I'm exploring the unknown. All I know is that other people claim they made it with a 300 Ohms coil that had a 6mm diameter soft iron core. That is all the information I have. I don't know the wire gauge, the number of turns, or the coil dimension.

In order to try reproducing this experiment I would like to know if I should better use a ferrite core or an soft iron core. The frequency are low, below 20kHz.

Another question is the diameter. Will I gain in sensibility with a larger core diameter ?

It is surprisingly difficult to find soft iron cores. I found some in China and the smallest diameter is 10mm. I found ferrite cores of 8mm diameter.

I know that soft iron is easier to cut at the right dimension. I read that ferrite falls appart when we try to cut it with a conventional saw.

A last question is if the inductance of a coil is a directly linked to the sensibility to varying magnetic field. In other words, may I assume that the higher the inductance, the more sensible to magnetic field my coil will be ?

**EDIT** The output voltage of the coil is described to be in the microvolt range.

Comment: Four inch nail; saw the ends off, cut to length. Heat to cherry red and allow to cool slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *if I should better use a ferrite core or an soft iron core. The
> frequency are low, below 20kHz.*

Soft iron will produce eddy currents in the presence of the magnetic field you are trying to sense. Those eddy currents will reduce your signal compared to ferrite so I would prefer to use ferrite.

> *Will I gain in sensibility with a larger core diameter ?*

I assume you mean sensitivity; a larger diameter winding will be more sensitive i.e. it will produce a bigger signal voltage because more magnetic flux will be attracted through the cross sectional area of the bigger winding.

> *I read that ferrite falls appart when we try to cut it with a
> conventional saw.*

You could pretty much grind ferrite down to small particles and reshape it in any way and get a decent result with glue. It's easily ground down and sand-papered. You could try using a fine grade hacksaw and I wouldn't be that concerned about little chips breaking-off because, the dominant path for magnetism is still via "the air" and, small to medium irregularities in the ferrite won't cause a problem. The ferrite core is just a "concentrator" of flux and it can be any shape and give pretty much the same benefits.

> *may I assume that the higher the inductance, the more sensible to
> magnetic field my coil will be ?*

Inductance is a by-product - the sensitivity of the coil is related to number of turns and loop diameter. More turns means more inductance.

Comment: Thank you very much. your answer help me a lot. Regarding the word sensibility, I was caught by a faux ami. I’m french and "sensibiilté" translates into sensitivity, not sensibility. Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: I than had another question. It may be that the magnetic field that I plan to measure varies a lot in space. I thus intuitively assumed that if I have a ferrite core of a big diameter, it will average the magnetic field at its top in contact with the source of magnetic field. Would I avoid averaging by shaping the ferrite core with a sharp point like a pencil ? Will it reduce the magnetic field measured ?

Comment: @chmike A bigger coil will average the magnetic field. If you want higher spatial resolution you should use a smaller diameter. Sharpening the ferrite core won't make any difference; it's the general mass of ferrite that attracts (concentrates) magnetic field lines through the coil.

Comment: thank you. I had one last question. I assume I have to position the coil with the ferrite core pointing and close to the thing emitting the magnetic field I want to measure. So the coil turns would be tangent to the surface of the container. How would the length of the coil affect sensitivity ? Is it preferable to have a short coil with a larger external diameter, or a longer coil with smaller external diameter ? By length I mean height of the coil.

Comment: I do not understand this: *So the coil turns would be tangent to the surface of the container.* - what container? Coil winding i.e. stacked and short vs unstacked and long largely determine the self resonant frequency of the resulting inductance. Long and unstacked means a higher resonant frequency.

Comment: The source of magnetic field is a substance diluted in water and the container would be for instance an Eppendorf. I would like to measure the low frequency magnetic field variations produced by the product by using an inductance coil. How should I orient the ferrite core in respect to the Eppendorf to maximize the induction in the coil and the amplitude of the tension at the coil terminals that I would measure with an oscilloscope ?

Comment: I don't know what an Eppendorf is but, the ferrite core should be axially in line with the lines of magnetic flux to be measured.